# OneSignal onOpened not called if app is closed

Tags: react-native, onesignal

I have an issue with the onOpened function of oneSignal (happens on iOS and Android). When I receive a push notification, clicking on it opens the app. I have a code in the app, that gets the notification text on the onOpened function and opens another screen inside the app, to display the full notification text.

But clicking the notification it opens the app, but does nothing else. When I close the app and reopen it, the other screen opens with the full notification text.

So, first time app opens on click notification, nothing happens, close app and opening it a second time, it works.

I use the following code in the App.js:

```
componentDidMount () {
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
}
onOpened(openResult) {
    console.log('Message: ', openResult.notification.payload.body);
    console.log('Data: ', openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
    console.log('isActive: ', openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
    console.log('openResult: ', openResult);
    if (openResult.notification.payload.body !== '') {
        const pushTitle = openResult.notification.payload.title;
        const pushBody = openResult.notification.payload.body;
        AsyncStorage.multiSet([['pushtitle', pushTitle], ['pushbody', pushBody]]);
    }
};
```

On the home component (the first screen):

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["pushtitle", "pushbody"]).then(responses => {
        responses.map((result, i, response) => {
            if (response[1][1] !== '' && response[1][1] !== null) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    navigation.navigate('PushDetails', {
                        title: response[0][1],
                        body: response[1][1]
                    });
                }, 100)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

The "PushDetails" is the extra screen to show the full notification text.

The push notifications are send from an external page using the oneSignal Api.

Anybody an idea what is going on?